# Hashsets and size method

Tags: java, string, hashset

Well I have a hashset of strings and I want to use size()
the problem is i dont know if hashsets size can be bigger then 2,147,483,647

and if i can get their size using bigint not int "so i wont be limited to 2,147,483,647" ?

the point I am asking is not the size only , but i want to know if i can get it's size using big int since a limit of a hashset can be memory

Comment: it is very unclear what you are asking

Comment: They cannot. Do you need them to be?

Comment: Well i learned that they are limitless , but if they are limitless they should be used with a limitless priv. type .. not int